# Populating required html form input field with setAttribute gives an error when trying to go to next form step

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

**FIXED**
// As the form is created using a WP Plugin, it seems the `required` is set on the parent div as opposed to on the input field.

I am using javascript to populate a required form input field using `.setAttribute(value, name)`

The field is definitely populated and I have confirmed this on the UI however as it is a multistep form, when clicking next to go to the next step, I am still receiving an error on that field?

Does the DOM believe the field wasn't populated as it wasn't interacted with by the user?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: In addition to providing the code, `I am still receiving an error on that field`: what's the error message?

Comment: The error message is this field is required. As for the code, the form is created via a WP Plugin so I only have the JS code that I have written.